# If an array is not sorted, binarySearch returns a random index; what is the logic behind the returned index?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

If I have an array that looks like this:

```
int[] arr = {6, 12, 3, 9, 8, 25, 10};
```

Why does this return `-2`:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 8);
```

I understand that `binarySearch` only works if the array is sorted. My question is what determines the returned index?

Comment: Look at the code? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java?av=f#1900

Comment: It isn't random, it's undefined. 'If it is not sorted, the results are undefined', and so therefore is the process via which they are generated.

Comment: No, it 'basically' returns an undefined result.

Comment: @EJP there's logic behind that return value .... read the docs

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović I have not only read but quoted *verbatim* from the docs. What part of 'if it is not sorted, the results are undefined' don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP  It doesn't return undefined but rather the approximated required position of the element, you should read up what assylias linked where it clearly states what the return value is and how it's calculated ... the fact it doesn't make much sense for unsorted arrays is valid but it still doesn't return undefined but an actual value

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović For the fourth time, the results are undefined. What any specific implementation may do is irrelevant in the face of that clear and unambiguous specification.

Comment: But @EJP, it will not always be undefined, right? If the value is found at any iteration, it will give the location of the element. That's why random.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović I got it from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte[],%20byte)). You would be better off reading it, instead of posting yet more baseless supposition.

Comment: @Yash You are arguing with the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte[],%20byte)), not with me.

Comment: @EJP Apologies! I just read the whole thing. I misunderstood the Oracle implementation as universal.

Comment: @Yash "Undefined" doesn't exclude the possibility that it might sometimes return the correct result. "Random" would imply that there is actual randomness involved; there isn't, the algorithm just returns arbitrary results which may or may not be correct.

Comment: To add some pettifoggery, the use of "undefined" in the Javadoc is somewhat debatable, as the result of `binarySearch` in terms of its input arguments is strictly deterministic and thus - in a certain sense - well defined. So it pretty much depends on our definition of undefinedness :-)

Comment: I agree with you @GyroGearless which I think makes my answer perfectly valid

Comment: `Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.` For all practical purposes, a negative index in an array is actually `undefined`. Agreeing with @EJP

Comment: @GyroGearless Only if you assume that the binary search algorithm is actually executed to the end. The specification permits it to act any way it likes if it detects disorder.

Comment: @EJP The question at hand is the logic behind the calculated value `-2` and not your interpretation of it as undefined or not ...

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović The question at hand is, and I quote, 'what determines the returned index', and the answer is that nothing determines it, because it is 'undefined', and that is not an 'interpretation', it is another *verbatim* quotation.

Comment: @EJP You're confusing people so I would ask you to stop with your lame logic, the return index is a value and as such it has logic behind it. If that logic isn't sound for unsorted arrays it doesn't matter and you can call it whatever you want but 'undefined' as return value isn't a valid answer. You haven't supported your claims with anything other then _it's written in the docs_ so instead of talking maybe you would like to make a better answer (with explanation) then me...

Answer (score 3):

As @assylias mentioned in the comments the documentation for [binarySearch](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java?av=f#1900) I can quote from it

> **Returns:**
>   index of the search key, if it is contained in the array within the specified range; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element in the range greater than the key, or toIndex if all elements in the range are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

So basically this is what happens in your attempt to search unsorted array:

`{6, 12, 3, 9, 8, 25, 10}`

- it takes middle element `9` and compares it to your searched element `8`, since `8` is lower it takes lower half `{6, 12, 3}`
- in second step it compares `12` to `8` and since `8` is again lower it takes lower half `{6}`
- `6` doesn't equal `8` and since it's the last element it didn't find what you wanted
- it returns `(-(insertion point) - 1)` where `insertion point` is

  > the index of the first element in the range greater than the key
- in your case that index is `1` since first element greater then `8` is `12` and it's index is `1`
- when you put that into equation it returns `(-1 - 1)` which equals `-2`

Hope I have answered your question.

Comment: What it says in the `@returns` part of the Javadoc is irrelevant when it has already been stated that the results are undefined if the array isn't sorted. Any implementation is entitled in that circumstance to do nothing, or loop forever, or return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, or throw a runtime exception, or dump core, or burst into flames, if the specified preconditions are not met.